# Drag Files come across Sandbox(__CFPasteboardIssueSandboxExtensionForPath)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sandbox, nspasteboard

I processed drag operation from browser view to custom view.It work well in snow lepoard,but not in Mountain Lion with sandbox.

```
in browser view:
    NSMutableArray* urls = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
..............put some NSUrl to urls array....................
    [pasteboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithArray:urls]];

in my receive custom view:
    NSArray* pasteboardItems = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString class]] options:nil];
    NSArray* pasteboardItems2 = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL class]] options:nil];
    NSArray* pasteboardItems3 = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSImage class]] options:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",pasteboardItems);
    NSLog(@"%@",pasteboardItems2);
    NSLog(@"%@",pasteboardItems3);
my log is:
    2012-08-09 18:33:43.886 iCollage[6885:303] __CFPasteboardIssueSandboxExtensionForPath: error for [/Users/xxxx/Library/Containers/xxxxxxxxxxxx/Data/Downloads/1343902069.jpg]
    2012-08-09 18:33:44.546 iCollage[6885:303] ( "file://localhost/Users/xxx/Library/Containers/xxxxxxxx/Data/Downloads/1343902069.jpg")
    2012-08-09 18:33:44.547 iCollage[6885:303] ( "file://localhost/Users/xxxxx/Library/Containers/xxxxxx/Data/Downloads/1343902069.jpg")
    2012-08-09 18:33:44.547 iCollage[6885:303] ()
```

my question is:

1.how to fix this error __CFPasteboardIssueSandboxExtensionForPath;I refer the docs and found nothing about that.I am ensuer that i have the permission to access the file!google says, may be "startAccessingSecurityScopedResource" will help me, then i try and failed

2.why pasteboardItems2 have value?i write to pasteboard only url but not string.It disgusted me that I can get the url both from NSString type and NSUrl type! (I try drag a file from iFinder, the url will only exist in pasteboardItems but not pasteboardItems2).Anybody know why? I think the first problem will auto fixed when some one help me fix this problem.

Comment: Have you found the way to fix this issue ? I am also getting this error :(

Comment: @Aravindhanarvi u can try bookmark-scope

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html) answer question 1:

> **Important**: Although you can support dragging file paths, in general,
>   you should avoid doing so unless you are certain that the destination
>   app will never be run in an app sandbox. If you use an NSString, OS X
>   has no way to know whether that string should be interpreted as a
>   path; thus, OS X does not expand the destination app’s sandbox to
>   allow access to the file or directory at that location. Instead, use
>   an NSURL, a bookmark, or a filename pasteboard type.

WRT to question 2, it looks like you have pasted URLs so reading `NSURL` objects would seem to be correct.  However I think you should implement the dragging using the following code (also from the link above):

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType] ) {
        NSArray *files = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
        int numberOfFiles = [files count];
        // Perform operation using the list of files
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [generate security-scoped URL bookmark data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/bookmarkDataWithOptions%3aincludingResourceValuesForKeys%3arelativeToURL%3aerror%3a) on the sender side, and [turn that data back into a URL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLByResolvingBookmarkData%3aoptions%3arelativeToURL%3abookmarkDataIsStale%3aerror%3a) on the receiver side. There's some other stuff you have to do after that when you want to actually access the URL; [the documentation elaborates](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16).

The receiving application, when running in a sandbox, will not be able to handle bare paths. This is a core part of being sandboxed; you are not allowed to use bare paths or their corresponding URLs to access files that aren't in your sandbox container and haven't been explicitly handed to you by the user.

Comment: @AchillesWang you can use this class to wrap up persisting a security-scoped URL bookmark. https://github.com/leighmcculloch/AppSandboxFileAccess

Answer (score 0):

Your **pasteboardItems** read object of NSString type, but you dragged a file(with jpg extension), you should register for NSString type in your init method:

```
[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSPasteboardTypeString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Document Types defined in your application so that the sandboxing mechanism knows your application should be opening files with those extensions. You can do this by clicking the project on the left in Xcode, and in the Info tab, under Document Types add a new document type for each extension.

You just need to fill in the `name` and `extensions` field.

Also if you want to persist your permission to access the files dragged onto your application, you can use this class to wrap up all that logic. https://github.com/leighmcculloch/AppSandboxFileAccess